# How do i pass two text inputs into ActionResult method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been working on a large project for a few days. Its all finished except for this part. I'm trying to pass 2 text boxes into my home controller method.

I've tried to use "model." and "item." but with no luck. it always passes null

```
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Display", "Home", FormMethod.Post)
</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div>
        Month:<input type="text" name="Month" id="MonthInput">
        Extra:<input type="text" name="Extra" id="ExtraInput"><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default"> <br> <br>
    </div>
}
```

and in the home controller is

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Display(String Month, String Extra)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
             ...
             return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return view;
}
```

I want it to pass whatever value is typed in the textboxes when the "Add" Button is clicked but it gives null

Comment: @using(Html.BeginForm ... will render a form tag, but then you have a second <form action="/action_page.php">  so you have a form in a form, is that intended?  Assuming MVC convention, the @using(Html.BeginForm with no parameters render the form action attribute as the controller that rendered the page, but in your second form you have a PHP action url. Again, is that what you intended?  Lastly, MVC forms will typically bind to the Model passed to the view. Is there anything like this at the top of your view:  @model MyApp.Models.Student

Comment: i have @model IEnumerable<ASPCalcSQLNewComp.Models.AmorView>. The textbox portion is posted inside a view with preset list template using the model AmorView.

Comment: Post method only accept one parameter from the body. So it will good to pass model and then at the controller action method you should pass that model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

In View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Display", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
 {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div>
    Month:<input type="text" name="Month" id="MonthInput">
    Extra:<input type="text" name="Extra" id="ExtraInput"><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default"> <br> <br>
    </div>
}
```

In Controller,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Display(SomeClass someClass)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         ...
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return view;
}
```

Create Normal class name SomeClass, name as per your requirment,

```
public class SomeClass{
 public string Month {get;set;}
 public string Extra {get;set;}
}
```

the name attribute of inputs should match to properties of SomeClass, it will map automatically, you then can access the value by using someClass object

```
  someClass.Month and someClass.Extra
```

Comment: Thank You so much. This Fixed it entirely. I couldn't find anything online to fix it. you are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

In order to correctly map to the action's parameters, you must use the `name` attribute.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Display", "Home"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div>
            Month:<input type="text" name="Month" id="MonthInput">
            Extra:<input type="text" name="Extra" id="ExtraInput"><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default">
    </div>
}
```

Totally unrelated, but it seems you have 2 nested forms and one of them POSTs to a `php` page. Is that desired?

Also, remove the following code because it does not make any sense:

```
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Display", "Home", FormMethod.Post)
</p>
```

Comment: I can take those out. just changing it to name instead of id still returned null

Comment: I've edited my code. Look at the last version (where you have both, name and id).

Comment: Just Edited the code and posted above. Still only Returns Null

Comment: Can you delete `<form action="/action_page.php">` from your html?

Comment: only if i replace it with a div class or something similar

Comment: Sure, you can transform it into a <div></div>.

Comment: yeah but it still returns null values

Comment: Just to be sure, can you update the question with the latest version of the code?

Comment: Thank You for your help but @satsvelke fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

To add on to the previous answer, I would suggest accepting the form as a FormCollection in the controller, because the form does not seem to be tied to the model:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Display(FormCollection collection)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string month = collection["Month"];
            string extra = collection["Extra"];

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Or even create a simple class that has the two variables, so the framework does the mapping

Comment: Thank You for your help but @satsvelke fixed it

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Your.Models
{
    public class DisplayModel
    {
        public string Month {get;set;}
        public string Extra {get;set;}
    }
}

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Display(DisplayModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string month = model.Month;
            string extra = model.Extra;

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }

@using Your.Models
@model DisplayModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Display", "Home", new { id="displayview" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div>
            Month:<input type="text" name="Month" id="MonthInput">
            Extra:<input type="text" name="Extra" id="ExtraInput"><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default">
    </div>
}
```